# Can't remove an OS X user account

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I installed some development environment which created a postgres user account. The user is actually an OS X user account with the name of 'postgres'. This is different from a user account within postgres.

I don't remember what it was, it was some time ago (perhaps MAMP, but I don't know whether MAMP even supports postgres).

Anyway, this was later uninstalled using the provided uninstaller.

Now when I log into my Mac, the postgres user always appears. But there is no trace of it in *System Preferences » User Accounts*, and there's no entry for it in `/etc/passwd`.

What is prompting OS X to list the user account in the login screen? I'm struggling to figure out where else to remove it from.

Comment: This is more of a question for superuser or serverfault.

Comment: have you looked at : http://linux.die.net/man/1/dropuser

Comment: @senfo, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Kassym, thanks, but the user account is an OSX one called postgres, not a database user account inside postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the terminal based DSCL command (see `man dscl`) to remove user accounts. Something like this may do the trick:

```
sudo dscl . -delete /users/postgres
```

Comment: My problem disappeared anyway, because I moved to Lion and did a fresh install. I suspect your solution would have worked though, I'll make a note of it for future, thanks :)